# Grais listing based on embedded date field not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to grails and trying to get a list of Domain based on Embedded class's date field.

Below are Working fine

```
def res = User.findAll { lt 'createdDateTime', new Date }

def res = User.findAll { eq 'account.name', 'JOHN' }
```

But,

```
def res = User.findAll { lt 'account.createdDateTime', new Date }
```

the above always return empty list.

'Account' class is embedded into User class

**User.groovy**

```
class User {
   String name
   Integer age
   Date ctratedDateTime // test
   Account account
   static embedded = [
      'account'
   ]
}
```

**Account.groovy**

```
class Account {
    String userName
    String password
    Date createdDateTime
}


def res = User.findAll { 
  account{ 
    lt 'createdDateTime', new Date 
  }
}
```

For above getting the following error

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Executing action [list] of controller [com.test.UserController]  caused exception: Runtime error executing action
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.ControllerExecutionException: Runtime error executing action
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test.UserController$_getFilteredForexRates_closure9.<init>(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lgroovy/lang/Reference;)V
at com.test.UserController$$EOqgV3Um.getFilteredForexRates(UserController.groovy:172)
at com.test.UserController$_closure5$$EOqgV3Um.doCall(UserController.groovy:109)
... 5 more
```

Am I doing in a correct way? Please suggest me the way to resolve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should use a nested closure:

```
def res = User.withCriteria{ 
  account{ 
    lt 'createdDateTime', new Date 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting NoSuchMethodError when running this.

Comment: post the stacktrace also

Comment: `findAll()` doesn't allow to build the proper `criteria query`. Use e.g. `withCriteria` instead. see the update